# Factory pattern in Rust

Tags: rust

I have a `Terminal` and a `TerminalFactory` type. What I want to achieve is a factory pattern or at least an implementation that is similar to it in regards to some key aspects.

In particular, I want every `Terminal` to have specific properties (e.G. `id`) that are set by `TerminalFactory`. In GRASP terms, `TerminalFactory` is the Creator and the Information Expert because it knows `next_id`.

`TerminalFactory` is not a singleton, it is an instance that will be injected in a container that will be handed around where necessary (I'm trying to implement an application based on the composite pattern to achieve the OCP of SOLID).

It looks like everything is in line with the fact that Rust discourages static state unless it's `unsafe` code.

The problem now is that instances of `Terminal` have an `id` which should not be set by arbitrary code. Therefore, it's not `pub`. On the other hand, it can be gotten. So I added a public getter, like this:

```rust
pub struct Terminal {
    id: u32, // private
    pub name: String
}

impl Terminal {
    pub fn get_id(self: &Self) -> u32 {
        self.id
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, there is no `friend` keyword in rust, no `static` state I can keep in the `Terminal` type and `TerminalFactory` cannot set `Terminal::id` during creation because it's not public.

I have the impression I can't implement the factory pattern correctly. Maybe I shouldn't even try to transfer "classical patterns" to Rust? Then what about the SOLID principles which are absolutely necessary to manage change in medium-scale applications (say, 50+ types and beyond 10000 lines of code)?

By adding an associate function `new(id : u32)` to `Terminal` I completely defeat the purpose of the factory. So this won't make sense, either.

As all of this code will be in a library that is consumed by other Rust code, how can I protect the consumer code from creating broken instances?

Comment: The unit of access control in Rust is the module, not the type. If `Terminal` and `TerminalFactory` are in the same module, they have access to the internals of each other. Is that sufficient to solve your problem?

Comment: First of all, thank you @SebastianRedl. This change in perspective is enlightening. I have to get back to the source code for some time to experiment and practice, but on a first glimpse it makes sense and may very well be a solution to the problem. What I fear is that in complex cases a module can grow quite large, but that is again a matter of "comfort zone". I expect that fine-grained separation as used in C#/Java will not be viable and be replaced by mid-grained separation. This makes all sense, after all it's a different paradigm, not just a different syntax. Thanks again!

Comment: Write an actual anwser if you want it to be accepted. As I said above, the "real answer" I will only discover after having practiced sufficiently this novel way of reasoning :)

Comment: BTW: the use of "module" in Rust is much closer to the historical definition in C as the confinement given by "class" in OO languages... probably I was "spoiled" by those languages or Rust is intentionally more C-like because it's a system language... hmmmmm.... maybe it's not fit to replace an "application language"? I have to ponder....

Comment: Rust is simply not an object-oriented language, so there is no class to be a unit of anything. However [`pub` itself can take additional *path modifiers*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/visibility-and-privacy.html#visibility-and-privacy) between "only visible in the source module" and "visible to everyone who has access to the type". And one of the important notes of non-pub fields is that a "module" encompasses all its submodules.

Comment: @Masklinn I know, I don't expect to find OOP constructs in Rust. What I need is to keep "change" at bay and organized code well. Can you point me to an online resource?

Comment: Rust **IS** object oriented language. The issue is that the majority/legacy OOP languages do not make a distinction between *inheritance* and *subtyping*. In order to be OOP, you need subtyping. Inheritance is considered a bad thing either way and is usually discouraged.

Comment: For what it's worth, I personally find the module-scoped visibility rules in Rust a lot more flexible, a lot more intuitive and overall much nicer to work with than the `friend`-based access in C++, which can be really limiting and cumbersome. Of course you need to adjust your design patterns to the language you are using, and you can't expect that design patterns developed for traditional OOP languages transfer one-to-one to Rust.

Comment: Since `id` should only be set on creation and not changed afterwards, why not just add a `new` function to your `Terminal`? ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bd9c7c7f0ea560f306b1e54cd5b68617))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put both types in the same module:

```rust
mod terminal {
    pub struct Terminal {
        id: u32,
        pub name: String
    }

    impl Terminal {
        pub fn get_id(&self) -> u32 {
            self.id
        }
    }

    pub struct TerminalFactory {
        next_id: u32,
    }

    impl TerminalFactory {
        pub fn new() -> Self {
            Self {
                next_id: 0,
            }
        }

        pub fn new_terminal(&mut self, name: &str) -> Terminal {
            let next_id = self.next_id;
            self.next_id += 1;
            Terminal {
                id: next_id,
                name: name.to_owned(),
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then this is OK:

```rust
let mut tf = terminal::TerminalFactory::new();

let t0 = tf.new_terminal("foo");
let t1 = tf.new_terminal("bar");

println!("{} {}", t0.get_id(), t0.name);
println!("{} {}", t1.get_id(), t1.name);
```

But this is not:

```rust
println!("{} {}", t0.id, t0.name); // error: private field
```

See [Visibility and privacy](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/visibility-and-privacy.html) for other scenarios.